# SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012 - login required to database "msdb"

Tags: sql-server-2012

I used **SQL Server 2008 – Developer Edition** for a few years only for use the **SQL Server Management Studio** and the **Import and Export Data** tool, no SQL Server instances are needed becouse I always use a remote server.

Now, I tryed the **SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012**, it have the **Import and Export Data** tool included, just what I need but now I have a issue, when I do a right-click on a database to access the **Generate Scripts** wizard I receive the following message:

```
Cannot open database "msdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'stocks'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4060)
```

I never had this issue with SQL Server 2008, 2005 and 2000. Anyone knows why the login to database "msdb" is required to do this action? Is there any alternative method to access the **Generate Scripts** wizard?

Comment: I don't have a machine with SSMS Express installed, but I was unable to reproduce this on a 2012 full instance of Management Studio against both 2008 and 2012 servers. Is the database you're right-clicking on a 2012 instance or an earlier version? Has the user `stocks` been *explicitly* denied access? Can you try with the client tools from the Evaluation Edition of SQL Server? If that works then perhaps a $49 investment in the Developer Edition might be worthwhile. This doesn't sound like a valid limitation in the Express version of the client tools, but it's Microsoft, so who knows...

Comment: @charles.art.br Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue